# Calling a function in Android app A from a android app B

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an Android app **A** which generates a machine learning model **X** based on data collected on the device. I need any app **B** to be able to make a bunch of function calls to **X** without user of **B** getting interrupted in his/her work.So ideally should happen in the background. Is this something possible in the current version of Android OS? I have looked a little in intents and services. I am not sure if it would be enough. Please let me know how can I achieve this.

P.S. My expertise is in Web and Data Science, not Android Development, so asking this question.

Comment: "Is this something possible in current version of Android OS?" -- possibly, but it would depend a lot on what "any app B to be able to make a bunch of function calls to X" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare the calls will be simple text input and text output. But condition it to achieve this without interruptions to user activity. Is this possible with Intents?

Comment: "Is this possible with Intents?" -- possibly. Next question: what is your proposed security model? Saying "any app B to be able to make a bunch of function calls to X" suggests that you are not planning on any security.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Security is important. I only want a very small set of  functions to be accessible through wrapper functions.

Comment: My concern is more on the "any app B" part. Do you literally want malware authors to have access to these functions? And, if not, how you intend to constrain the "any" part of "any app B"?

Comment: @CommonsWare I will be using some form of  authentication to prevent that. And app B will have some permission system to restrict access to only user approved apps along with logging information.

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. That is a bit more hand-wavy than I was hoping for. But, what you describe should fit within the capabilities of a bound service. There are also ways you could use a started service or even broadcast `Intents` to achieve your IPC objectives.